# Adding a column from a dataframe i.e. df['constant'] to all the other columns of the dataframe df. When NAN + float appears return the float

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, numpy, null, addition

I have a dataframe df with columns a,b,c and constant.

```
   |a |b   |c   |constant|
id |  |    |    |        |
000|0 |0.2 |0.5 |0.7     |
111|0 |-0.3|0.1 |0.9     |
222|0 |NAN |0.6 |0.3     |
333|0 |1   |0.8 |0.5     |
444|0 |0.2 |1   |1.1     |
555|0 |0.8 |NAN |-0.3    |
666|0 |-0.5|-0.6|NAN     |
```

I would like to add the column df['constant'] to all the other columns of of the dataframe and replace the current columns with the sum.  i.e. df['a'] would be the same as df['constant'] since it is all 0's.  The new dataframe should look like this:

```
   |a   |b   |c   |constant|
id |    |    |    |        |
000|0.7 |0.9 |1.2 |0.7     |
111|0.9 |0.6 |1   |0.9     |
222|0.3 |0.3 |0.9 |0.3     |
333|0.5 |1.5 |1.3 |0.5     |
444|1.1 |1.3 |2.1 |1.1     |
555|-0.3|0.5 |-0.3|-0.3    |
666|0   |-0.5|-0.6|NAN     |
```

NOTE: if NAN is added to a float then the float should be returned

My 3 attempts are shown below:

attempt 1 used a function and pd.to_numeric

attempt 2 i used 2 function, def adds(x,y) i hoped would fix the type error

attempt 3 i tired doing the same as attempt 2 but with a lambda expression

```
df2['constant'] = pd.to_numeric(df2['constant'], errors='coerce')
df2['constant'] = df2['constant'].fillna(0)

dataframe_columns = ['a','b','c']

##attempt number 1
# add merged-constant across df
for c in dataframe_columns:
    df2[c] = pd.to_numeric(df2[c], errors='coerce')
    df2[c] = df2[c].add(df2['constant'])


##attempt number 2

def adds(x,y):
    if isinstance(x, float) and isinstance(y, float)==True:
        return x+y
    elif isinstance(x, float) and isinstance(y, object):
        return x
    elif isinstance(x, object) and isinstance(y, float):
        return y
    else:
        return y

# add merged-constant across df2
for c in dataframe_columns:
    df2[c] = adds(df2[c], dfc['constant'])


##attempt number 3
def adds(x,y):
    if isinstance(x, float) and isinstance(y, float)==True:
        return x+y
    elif isinstance(x, float) and isinstance(y, object):
        return x
    elif isinstance(x, object) and isinstance(y, float):
        return y
    else:
        return y

#lambda test add merged-constant across df2
for c in dataframe_columns:
    return c
df2[dataframe_columns] = df2.apply(lambda x: adds(x[dataframe_columns], x['constant']), axis =  1)
```

I would like a new dataframe were columns a, b and c all have the constant column added to its total as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `fillna`, `add`, and `join`

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c']].fillna(0).add(df['constant'].fillna(0), axis=0).join(df.constant)


Out[391]:
        a    b    c  constant
id
000   0.7  0.9  1.2       0.7
111   0.9  0.6  1.0       0.9
222   0.3  0.3  0.9       0.3
333   0.5  1.5  1.3       0.5
444   1.1  1.3  2.1       1.1
555  -0.3  0.5 -0.3      -0.3
666   0.0 -0.5 -0.6       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in pd.Series.add we have fill_value=0 (Not sure why dataframe +Series dose not work  ), so we just using that for each columns , then `concat` back `update` original df

```
df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
df.update(pd.concat([df[x].add(df.constant,fill_value=0) for x in df.columns[:-1]],keys=df.columns[:-1],axis=1))
df
Out[116]: 
     a    b    c  constant
0                         
1  0.7  0.9  1.2       0.7
2  0.9  0.6  1.0       0.9
3  0.3  0.3  0.9       0.3
4  0.5  1.5  1.3       0.5
5  1.1  1.3  2.1       1.1
6 -0.3  0.5 -0.3      -0.3
7  0.0 -0.5 -0.6       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but i forgot to specify that if there is an instance where NAN is added to NAN, the NAN will appear in the final dataframe.  Right now all NANS are converted to zeros. Unfortualty i need the NANs and zeros to be maintained, but act as zeros when added.